# Prevent Mathematica using previous result

Tags: memoization

How can I prevent mathematica from using the previous computation in new one? How do I make the code below to compute same amount of time without memorizing previous computation.

```
  In[25]:= AbsoluteTiming@Sum[i^3 + 4. i^2, {i, 1000000}]

Out[25]= {2.9587, 2.50002*10^23}

In[26]:= AbsoluteTiming@Sum[i^3 + 4. i^2, {i, 1000000}]

Out[26]= {2.64804, 2.50002*10^23}
```

Comment: Look up `ClearSystemCache[]`.

Comment: How reproducible is this?  I don't find the same thing happening [here](http://i.imgur.com/i4wfU5D.png)

Comment: I made a mistake, in the first I used `4.` in the second `4`. So the expressions were not equivalent. Corrected. Seems to be little memorization going on here. Still good to know the `ClearSystemCache[]`